# reload a div and not the whole page using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im trying to reload a table whenever the user hits the save button. but the problem is that the whole page is being reloaded.plz someone help.here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//save button listener  
$("#save").click(function(){
//receiving data entered by user from design.php  

     var name = $('#name').val();
     var email = $('#email').val();
     var telephone = $('#telephone').val();
     var username = $('#username').val();  
     var password=$('#password').val();
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: 'contactData.php',             
   data:{"name":name,"telephone":telephone,"email":email, "username":username, "password":password},
   // dataType:'json',
   success: function(data) {
 var result = JSON.parse(data);
       $("#validate").html(result.msg);
       if (result.msg="Your info has been sent")
           {
           $("#table").load("design.php");
           return false;
           }
   }//end of success
   });//end of  ajax
     });//end of listener
        });//end of javascript
```

and this is the div that i want to reload which is in the design.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>  
<title>Contact Info</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src='jquery1.js'></script>
<script src='jqueryTest.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Contact Information</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="name" >
<span class="error">* </span>
<br><br>
Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="email" >
<span class="error">* </span>
<br><br>
Telephone:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="telephone" >
<span class="error">* </span> 
<br><br>
UserName: <input type="text" id="username">
<span class="error">*</span> 
<br><br>
Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" id="password">
<span class="error">*</span>
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" >
<div id="validate"></div>
<div id="table">
<?php 
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $host = "localhost";

  $connector = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
      or die("Unable to connect");

  $selected = mysql_select_db("mysql", $connector)
    or die("Unable to connect");

  //execute the SQL query and return records
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ");
  ?>
<table border="2" style= "background-color: #99ffcc; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;">
<thead>
  <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      <tbody class="container">
        <?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
          {
           echo "<tr>
                 <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['telephone']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['email']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['username']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['password']}</td>
                 </tr>\n";
           }
        ?>
     </tbody>    
   </tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

when hitting the save button the whole page is being reloaded.what is the solution for div table only to be reloaded

Comment: can not see your save button is that hidden? :D

Comment: What type of element is `#save`?

Comment: It would be interesting to see your form, where you "hit the save button". Did you made sure, that it is not initiating the submit action? Some more code would be nice. And you maybe need a `event.stopPropagation()` in you click / submit listener.

Comment: Have you tried putting 'return false' at the end of the click event? Submit buttons naturally reload the page or go to a desired page unless you tell it not to.

Comment: It seems Jacob Krall is on to something. if `#save` is an `input[type=submit]`, the form's action will fire, even while you wait for the response to the AJAX call. Try changing it to a simple anchor tag with `href="#"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have only `<div id="table">` in design.php file, in your original file have the `<div id="show-table">` and in the success function of ajax store the whole page as Object and append to the div dynamically like this

```
var Obj = load('design.php');
$('#show-table').html(Obj);
```

Remember the design.php file has to separate file from the file where you have written the script